# How do I pass $(this) to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing, this

My code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hCount = 0,
        eCount = 0,
        nCount = 0,
        mCount = 0;

$("#head").click(function() {
        var pPos = counter(hCount);
        $(this).animate({left:pPos+"px"}, 1000);
    });

function counter(count)
{
    count++;
    if(count === 10)
    {
        count = 0;
        pPos = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var pPos = $(this).css('left');
        pPos = pPos.substring(0,(pPos.length-2))
        pPos -= 367;

    }

    return pPos;
}
```

I get an error stating

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

I have no idea what's causing this error.

Also, how can I pass the function `counter()` the value of `$(this)` in `$("#head").click`? I can't directly mention `$("#head")` because I'll repeat this functionality with more divs, other than `#head`, while reusing the code in the function counter.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions. Ask one or the other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just extend counter function with `elem` argument and pass it within click handling:

```
function counter(count, elem){
   // ...
}

$("#head").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var pPos = counter(hCount, elem);
    elem.animate({left:pPos+"px"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but now apparently I have a new problem. I need to pass the value of both `pPos` and `count` from function counter without the use of global variables. Any ideas about what could be done?

Comment: return list from counter: return [pPos, counter], and get pPos as result[0] and count as result[1], where result=counter()

Comment: One final question, sir.. Is there any way I could eliminate the global variables hCount, eCount, nCount and mCount?

Comment: that's not trivial problem, see http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/ article

Comment: @SomenathSinha Also note that your hCount, eCount ... not global vars.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` is just an object like any other. Simply pass it into your function:

```
counter(hCount, $(this));
....

function counter(count, thisFromPreviousFunction)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

This comes from the line 
 `var pPos = $(this).css('left');`

as `$(this)` isn't defined in your function *(the function isn't related to a Selector, so $(this) doesn't exists as you think).*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hCount = 0,
        eCount = 0,
        nCount = 0,
        mCount = 0;

  $("#head").click(function() {
    var pPos = counter(hCount, $(this)); // Pass the selector
    $(this).animate({left:pPos+"px"}, 1000);
  });

  function counter(count, selector) {
      count++;
      if(count === 10)  {
          count = 0;
          pPos = 0;
      }
      else {
          var pPos = selector.css('left'); // Use the given selector
          pPos = pPos.substring(0,(pPos.length-2))
          pPos -= 367;
      }
      return pPos;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yw2b4tyt/